# pointer from cell.contentView viewWithTag is set to nil (0) when pointer.tag is set

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

In the delegate of UITableViewCell, when I get a pointer to a previously allocated UIButton...
UIButton* PWR_RX_tracking_button = (UIButton*)  [cell.contentView viewWithTag: BASE_UIBUTTON_TAG    +    cell_UIButton_index++ ];
...this pointer will get rest to nil (0) if I do:
PWR_RX_tracking_button.tag = 0;
...or set it to any value.

I display a UITableView that shows 2 cells.
1st time cellForRowAtIndexPath() is called, 
UI controls for 1st cell are allocated, and one set of 16 UI controls is displayed (images, labels, text, some buttons).

2nd time cellForRowAtIndexPath() is called:
UI controls for 2nd cell are allocated, and this cell is blank.

A little later, 2 sets of controls need to be displayed, so:
3rd time cellForRowAtIndexPath() is called:
the "cell.contentView viewWithTag" to the last button is now 0 (nil)!!!!  It is no longer allocated.
so only some of 1st set of 16 UI controls is displayed.
However, 2nd set of UI controls within same cell displays ok -- its UI controls are still allocated.

Is this a memory management issue?  Am I failing to retain somehow?
I'm using XCODE 5.0.2
Has automatic ARC because it generates error if I add autorelease etc.

Here is cellForRowAtIndexPath () guts:

.m file...............

UITableView* device_charge_tableView[ TOTAL_TX_CHANNELS ];

```
 -(void)init_table
 {
            device_charge_tableView[ channel ] = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:tableFrame style:UITableViewStylePlain];

            device_charge_tableView[ channel ].rowHeight = device_charge_row_height;
            device_charge_tableView[ channel ].sectionFooterHeight = 0;
            device_charge_tableView[ channel ].sectionHeaderHeight = 0;
            device_charge_tableView[ channel ].scrollEnabled = YES;
            //new_system_device_tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
            //      device_charge_tableView[ channel ].userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            device_charge_tableView[ channel ].bounces = YES;

            device_charge_tableView[ channel ].delegate = self;
            device_charge_tableView[ channel ].dataSource = self;
            device_charge_tableView[ channel ].allowsSelection = NO;
            device_charge_tableView[ channel ].tag = channel;

            //  device_charge_tableView[ channel ].autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
            charge_record_index = expected_charge_index = 0;
            [device_charge_tableView[ channel ]  reloadData];               // display channel's TableView
            [[self view] addSubview:   device_charge_tableView[ channel ]];
 }


 -(void)redisplay
 {
     ...
     [device_charge_tableView[ 0 ]  reloadData];    
     ...
 }




- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

            return 2;      // add 1 row for a nice looking blank cell at end
}



- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        return device_charge_row_height;  
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        ...
            NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s_%d",device_off_table ? "OFF" : "CHG", table_cell_index];
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
                /* Though it's UITableViewCellStyleDefault, the three defaults (image, label, detail label) are nil
                if not set. */      
                // UI controls must be preset for re-use, to prevent memory leak:  
                // Allocate contiguous range of tags for each type of UI control for all devices, in this cell, once per boot:
                    int instance;
                    for(  instance=0; instance < total_cell_UILabels; ++instance )
                    {
                        ///////////////   A L L O C A T E   C E L L   L A B E L S   ///////////////

                        UILabel*   cell_UILabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];  // allocate next UI control
                        [cell.contentView addSubview: cell_UILabel ];                           // add it permanently to the cell
                        cell_UILabel.tag = BASE_UILABEL_TAG + instance;                         // assign unique ID for later lookup
                        if( dbg_cell )      printf( " tag_%d ", cell_UILabel.tag );
                    }
                    for(  instance=0; instance < total_cell_UITextViews; ++instance )
                    {
                        ///////////////   A L L O C A T E   C E L L   T E X T V I E W S   ///////////////

                        UITextView*   cell_UITextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
                        [cell.contentView addSubview: cell_UITextView ];
                        cell_UITextView.tag = BASE_UITEXTVIEW_TAG + instance;
                        if( dbg_cell )      printf( " tag_%d ", cell_UITextView.tag );
                    }
                    for(  instance=0; instance < total_cell_UIImageViews ; ++instance )
                    {
                        ///////////////   A L L O C A T E   C E L L   I M A G E V I E W S   ///////////////

                        UIImageView*   cell_UIImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
                        [cell.contentView addSubview: cell_UIImageView ];
                        cell_UIImageView.tag = BASE_UIIMAGEVIEW_TAG + instance;
                        if( dbg_cell )      printf( " tag_%d ", cell_UIImageView.tag );
                    }
                    // Allocate invisible buttons:
                        for(  instance=0; instance < total_cell_UIButtons ; ++instance )
                        {
                            ///////////////   A L L O C A T E   C E L L   B U T T O N S   ///////////////

                            UIButton*   cell_UIButton = [UIButton  buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
                            [cell_UIButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                            cell_UIButton.frame = CGRectZero;

                            [cell.contentView addSubview: cell_UIButton ];
                            cell_UIButton.tag = BASE_UIBUTTON_TAG + instance;
                            if( dbg_cell )      printf( " tag_%d ", cell_UIButton.tag );
                        }
                if( dbg_cell )      printf("\n");
            }

        ...

        for(;;)     // LOOP for times, to display 4 sets of UI controls next to each other:
        {

                // Get pointers to all possible UI controls of this UITableViewCell:
                    UILabel* PWR_RX_title                       = (UILabel*)    [cell.contentView viewWithTag: BASE_UILABEL_TAG     +    cell_UILabel_index++ ];
                    UILabel* PWR_RX_footer                      = (UILabel*)    [cell.contentView viewWithTag: BASE_UILABEL_TAG     +    cell_UILabel_index++ ];    
                    UILabel* PWR_RX_voltage                     = (UILabel*)    [cell.contentView viewWithTag: BASE_UILABEL_TAG     +    cell_UILabel_index++ ];
                    UILabel* PWR_RX_rssi                        = (UILabel*)    [cell.contentView viewWithTag: BASE_UILABEL_TAG     +    cell_UILabel_index++ ];
                    UILabel* PWR_RX_power                       = (UILabel*)    [cell.contentView viewWithTag: BASE_UILABEL_TAG     +    cell_UILabel_index++ ];
                    UILabel* client_type_label                  = (UILabel*)    [cell.contentView viewWithTag: BASE_UILABEL_TAG     +    cell_UILabel_index++ ];
                    UILabel* battery_percent_text               = (UILabel*)    [cell.contentView viewWithTag: BASE_UILABEL_TAG     +    cell_UILabel_index++ ];
                    UILabel* client_device_title                = (UILabel*)    [cell.contentView viewWithTag: BASE_UILABEL_TAG     +    cell_UILabel_index++ ];
                    UITextView* PWR_RX_cover_box                = (UITextView*) [cell.contentView viewWithTag: BASE_UITEXTVIEW_TAG  +    cell_UITextView_index++ ]; 
                    UIImageView* device_icon_UIImageView        = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag: BASE_UIIMAGEVIEW_TAG +    cell_UIImageView_index++ ];
                    UIImageView* energy_glow_UIImageView        = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag: BASE_UIIMAGEVIEW_TAG +    cell_UIImageView_index++ ];
                    UIImageView* battery_level_icon             = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag: BASE_UIIMAGEVIEW_TAG +    cell_UIImageView_index++ ];
                    UIButton* PWR_RX_charge_button              = (UIButton*)   [cell.contentView viewWithTag: BASE_UIBUTTON_TAG    +    cell_UIButton_index++ ];       
                    UIButton* invisible_drag_button             = (UIButton*)   [cell.contentView viewWithTag: BASE_UIBUTTON_TAG    +    cell_UIButton_index++ ];       
                    UIButton* PWR_RX_tracking_button            = (UIButton*)   [cell.contentView viewWithTag: BASE_UIBUTTON_TAG    +    cell_UIButton_index++ ];
```

...

```
                PWR_RX_tracking_button.frame = CGRectMake   (x,y + h * 2/3, w, h/3);    // lower quarter of icon        !!! NORMAL

                        PWR_RX_tracking_button.tag = area_device_status[ channel ][ PWR_RX_status_index ].serno_value;



                    >>>>>>>>>>>>>  ERROR IS:  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                    1ST TIME PWR_RX_tracking_button IS OKAY.
                    2ND TIME, PWR_RX_tracking_button = 0  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

WHY DOES SETTING UIBUTTON TAG IN CELL SET POINTER TO BUTTON TO 0??
IF .tag = 0;  INSTEAD, PROBLEM STILL OCCURS.
IF THE .tag = IS COMMENTED OUT, PROBLEM GOES AWAY.

```
                        [PWR_RX_tracking_button addTarget:self 
                                   action:@selector( delegate_tracking_button: )
                         forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside ];


            ...


            ++cell_record_index;        // select next device record
            ++device_per_row_index;     // select next display device of row
            if( device_per_row_index < devices_per_cell )   // another device to display on this row?
                continue;   // GO DISPLAY NEXT SET OF THE 4 SETS OF UI CONTROLS
            else
                break;      // ALL SETS have been shown
        }   

        // CHECK FOR DESIGN ERROR, IF UI control array limited exceeded:
        if(     cell_UILabel_index > total_cell_UILabels        + UI_controls_per_cell * table_cell_index 
            ||  cell_UIImageView_index > total_cell_UIImageViews    + UI_controls_per_cell * table_cell_index 
            ||  cell_UITextView_index > total_cell_UITextViews      + UI_controls_per_cell * table_cell_index 
            ||  cell_UIButton_index > total_cell_UIButtons      + UI_controls_per_cell * table_cell_index )
        {
            printf("\n cell_UILabel_index cell_UIImageView_index cell_UITextView_index cell_UIButton_index  %d %d %d %d", cell_UILabel_index, cell_UIImageView_index, cell_UITextView_index, cell_UIButton_index );
            printf("\n total_cell_UILabels total_cell_UITextViews total_cell_UIImageViews  %d %d %d %d", 
                total_cell_UILabels, total_cell_UITextViews, total_cell_UIImageViews, total_cell_UIButtons );
            printf("   <<< MAX EXCEEDED!!  HALTED.");
            for(;;)  sleep(1);
        }
        save_record_index( cell_record_index, expected_cell_index, device_off_table );
                                                                                                                            if( dbg_cell )      printf(" HHH \n");
        return cell;
}   // cellForRowAtIndexPath()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh!

PROBLEM:
I was using .tag for two different purposes.
Its primary purpose was to index the UI controls for reuse.
But, I was re-assigning UIButton .tag's with data to be read when the button was pressed.
So, by clobbering the .tag, the UIButton could not be looked up again.

SOLUTION:
I can drop the data into an array indexed by the cell (row) index.  Then:
[There's a cool answer here on how a UIButton delegate can lookup the cell index.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612939/uibutton-tag-not-being-assigned-indexpath-row-after-6-cells)